# ReactiveForms Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Olá, estou tentando criar um component de formulário reutilizável utilizando o ReactiveForms. Como quando eu quiser utilizar um formulario, apenas passarei um array dos meus inputs desse formulário.

Porém estou com dúvidas se isso é realmente possível. No meu caso eu travei aqui:

```js
export class FormularioShared implements OnInit{
 
 formulario: FormGroup;
 @Input() inputs: InputsModels[];
 
 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){}
 ngOnInit(){
 this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
 [this.inputs[0].formControlName]: this.formBuilder.control('', Validators.required),
 });
 }
}
```

Quando não sei como inteirar no meu array de inputs para criar os controls do formbuilder! Gostaria de saber se isso é realmente possível??
Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem a sua dúvida, mas eu fiz uma pergunta no SO-En que acho que pode ser o que deseja, veja: [How to add a child component within parent component using React forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518397/how-to-add-a-child-component-within-parent-component-using-react-forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imaginando que seu InputModels tenha uma propriedade value e uma formControlName eu faria assim usando a função reduce do array:

```
  public construirForm(inputs: InputModels[]) {
        const formMap = inputs.reduce((dataAgg, iterator) => {
            const fmctrl =<AbstractControl> new FormControl(iterator.value);
            dataAgg[iterator.formControlName] =  fmctrl;     
            return dataAgg;
        }, {});
        return new FormGroup(formMap);           
    }
```

Comment: Funcionou dessa maneira, porem dessa forma, como poderia fazer os Validators?

Comment: const fmctrl =<AbstractControl> new FormControl(iterator.value, Validators.required);

Comment: ou   const fmctrl =<AbstractControl> new FormControl(iterator.value, iterator.validators);